# redefine default filtering behavior in Django templates

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have a project with many DecimalFields that are rendered in more than 300 templates. I would like that these decimal fields are rendered normalized. I don't care about precission or anything:

```
decimal.Decimal("10.0000").normalize()
```

I haven't found a way to change default rendering system. I know there is a humanize and a floatformat filter I could use in my templates. But I need a solution that doesn't mean editing all those files, even if a shell script could be written.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could create a subclass of `DecimalField` where you override `DecimalField.__str__` or `DecimalField.__unicode__` to suit your needs. This method is called whenever the value needs to be rendered in a template or whatnot. You would only need to change your models.

The code for the`Field` class is [here](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L386). `DecimalField` is a subclass of this. Documentation about subclassing `Field`: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#writing-a-field-subclass

Also, see this tip abount the `__unicode__` method: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#some-general-advice

Edit: I am waaay to tired to make any sense at the moment.

Comment: I thought format_number was kept for Oracle, I have changed format_number code directly in Django and nothing happens, it's not getting called whenever the value is rendered. Are you sure about what you say? There is also no documentation on this method in djangoproject. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you are right. I apologize for being confusing. See my edit, I think I got it right this time. :)

Comment: I have edited DecimalField's __unicode__ method to add a simple print to see when it gets called and I haven't seen the print anywhere I render the value in the template. Thanks for editing your answer, I'm starting to think my question has no answer.