# django smart decimal field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am creating an app that basically stores shoe sizes, along with other information. I have been using the Django Decimal field to store the sizes, however the decimal field stores sizes like 10 as 10.0, so my question is, is there a way to make or if already exists a field that when provided an int ( 10 ) it stores the value as int and when provided a decimal
( 10.5 ) then stores it as decimal ?

Comment: Well it won't actually store it as an int type in a DecimalField. You may want to look at writing a template tag or a model method to output a printed decimal-free number for whole numbers

Comment: i need the value to be stored as its received, so that i can import it from the database without having to worry about the .0

Comment: maybe just use a CharField with a strict clean method

Comment: This may have already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119151/redefine-default-filtering-behavior-in-django-templates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TBH for a shoe size field I'd probably use a CharField with choices attribute - there are a relatively small number of valid shoe sizes and that way you can format them how you want to.

If it's part of a Product model that may contain things other than shoes, a CharField for 'size' is useful because you can also store values like 'M', 'L', 'XXL' etc.

You won't need to do any math on the shoe sizes so there's no point to using a DecimalField.

For that reason it doesn't really matter what is saved in the db, only what you display and @j_syk had a couple of good alternative suggestions along those lines in the comments.

Comment: good point with the 'M', 'L' etc. Even some shoes are sized this way, like some slippers and sandals. Guess it depends on if the data stored is about a shoe or about a person's shoe size (i.e. i would never say that my shoe size is XL).

Comment: I have opted on using a charfield with choices, i figured its the easiest way for now :)

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't simply casting it to a string work for you? You can keep your storage as-is, but format the number to your liking when presenting your data.

```
>>> str(Decimal(10))
'10'
>>> str(Decimal(10.5))
'10.5'
>>> str(Decimal(10.0))
'10'
```

Comment: i've never thought about this, what do you think would be the best approach for this, meaning would i have to write a custom field in order to add this functionality ?

Comment: You could perhaps use a `CharField` with an [initial value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#initial) to present it as you wish (just cast it to a string). When saving it, the `Decimal` class will save it for you, so no worries there: that will work just fine.

Comment: But when the decimal class saves it, it will save it with the .o ?

Comment: It will convert it to a number, so yes, it saves all significant digits.

Answer (score 1):

I adopted this solution:

1. Create a custom [Django model Field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/)
2. Which return a custom `decimal.Decimal` instance that implements the trick in `__unicode__` because this is just a matter of representation

Here is the snippet:

```py
class PyPrettyDecimal(decimal.Decimal): 

    def __unicode__(self): 
        # TODO: to improve with decimal properties ?!? 
        mod = self - int(self) 
        if not mod: 
            rv = int(self) 
        else: 
            rv = self.quantize(mod.normalize()) 
        return unicode(rv) 

class PrettyDecimalField(models.DecimalField): 

    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase 

    def to_python(self, value): 
        if value is None: 
            return value 
        try: 
            return PyPrettyDecimal(value) 
        except decimal.InvalidOperation: 
            raise exceptions.ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid'])
```